# Is any permutation the product of two involutions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The abstract of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5319) says:

> *"It is well-known that any permutation can be written as a product of two involutions."*

I was looking for any web resource that can provide an affirmation and (hopefully easy) proof of this statement -- can anyone please help?

And if any permutation can indeed be written as a product of two involutions, are the following guesses correct?

1. If $P$ is a permutation and $X$ & $Y$ are involutions, and $P = XY$, then $P^{-1} = YX$
2. If $X$ & $Y$ are distinct involutions such that neither is the identity permutation $I$, then the permutation $XY$ is not an involution.
3. The only ways to express any involution $X$ as a product of two involutions is $X = XI$ & $X = IX$ (given that $I$ itself is an involution)

Thanks ...

Comment: A general factoid at work in Michael's excellent answer is the following. If $\alpha=(a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_m)$ is an $m$-cycle and $\beta=(b_1b_2b_3\ldots b_n)$ is an $n$-cycle **DISJOINT FROM $\alpha$**, then multiplying the product $\alpha\beta$ by the transposition $(a_1b_1)$ "fuses" them to an $(m+n)$-cycle:
$$
\alpha\beta(a_1b_1)=(a_1b_2b_3\ldots b_mb_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n).
$$ He is using this  repeatedly to form a cycle of a prescribed length as a product of two sets of disjoint 2-cycles. At least that's how I read it :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is there a name for this factoid, or any proof of it. Seems proof should be only by induction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please tell why swapped the subscripts ($m,n$) of the two strings: $\alpha, \beta.$ Am not clear, if the swap is correct even.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Let, $\alpha=(12345)$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5\\ 
2&3&4&5&1\\
\end{pmatrix}

Let, $\beta=(6789)$
\begin{pmatrix}
6&7&8&9\\
7&8&9&6\\
\end{pmatrix}

Then, your comment means: 
$\alpha\beta(16)= (1789623)=$
$$1\to7, 7\to8, 8\to9, 9\to6\to 1, 6\to2, 2 \to3.$$

But, have:
$(12345)(6789)(16)=$
$$1\to 6\to7, 6\to1\to 2, 7\to8, 8\to9, 9 \to6, 
2\to3, 3\to4, 4\to5, 5\to1.$$
So, it should be: 
$\alpha\beta(16)= (178962345).$

Comment: @jiten There was a typo with the subscripts. We get an $(m+n)$-cycle. Comments cannot be edited, so such typos linger. In your example case we get a 9-cycle.

Comment: @jiten I give a proof of this factoid as an exercise. It is not too difficult. Try it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your three numbered statements, $(1)$ is true (easy proof), but $(2)$ and $(3)$ are false.  A counter example for $(2)$ is obtained by taking $X = (1,2)$ and $Y = (3,4)$.  Then $XY = (1,2)(3,4)$ is an involution as well.  A counterexample for $(3)$ is obtained from this example as well; the involution $X = (1,2)(3,4)$ can be factored as $YZ$ where $Y = (1,2)$ and $Z = (3,4)$.

As for the statement in question, here's a quick proof sketch:

(1) By using the disjoint cycle decomposition, you can reduce to proving that the cycle $(1,2,3,\dots,n)$ can be written as a product of two involutions in $S_n$.

(2) To handle that case, draw $n$ vertices in the plane (labelled $1,2,\dots,n$) and connect the $n$ vertices by drawing $n-1$ edges.  This will make a unique (up to choice of direction to travel) path in your graph.  Label the edges $1,2,\dots,n-1$ in the order of the path.  For each edge, put the two vertices connected by that edge into a two-cycle.  Then form $\pi_1$, the product of the two-cycles formed in this way from *odd*-numbered edges, and $\pi_2$, the product of the two-cycles formed in this way from *even*-numbered edges.  Then the product $\pi_2 \pi_1$ is an $n$-cycle $\tau$.  This needs to be checked; in fact, if you number the vertices in the order of the path, then $\tau = (1,3,5,\dots, 6,4,2)$.  Conjugate the relation $\tau = \pi_2 \pi_1$ to get that $(1,2,\dots,n)$ is a product of two involutions.

Comment: For finite reflection groups, we know quite a lot about involutions... For instance it is comparatively easy to find their conjugacy classes. Is there a similar theorem there?
(about the number of involutions needed to factorize an arbitrary element of the reflection group...)