# Let $\tau \in S_{n} $. Show that there exists $\sigma \in S_{n} $ such that $\sigma \circ \tau =\tau ^{-1}\circ \sigma$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\tau \in S_{n} $. Show that there exists $\sigma \in S_{n} $ such that $\sigma \circ \tau =\tau ^{-1}\circ \sigma$.

Here $S_{n}$ is the symmetric group.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Prove the result for when $\tau$ is a cycle, and make sure $\sigma$ doesn't permute any elements apart from those cycled by $\tau$. Once you've done that, take an arbitrary $\tau$, write it in disjoint cycle form, and apply the result to each of those cycles in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Since [any permutation is the product of two involutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497637/is-any-permutation-the-product-of-two-involutions), write $\tau=\rho\sigma$ where $\rho^2=\sigma^2=I;$ then
$$\tau^{-1}\sigma=(\rho\sigma)^{-1}\sigma=(\sigma\rho)\sigma=\sigma(\rho\sigma)=\sigma\tau.$$

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Arthur's answer, suppose that $\tau$ is a cycle on $n$ elements. You can view $\tau$ as the map $x\mapsto x+1$ on $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$. Then, consider $\sigma(x)=2-x$ which gives a permutation of $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$ also.

You have

$$
\sigma(\tau(x))=2-(x+1)=1-x
$$

and

$$
\tau^{-1}(\sigma(x))=(2-x)-1=1-x
$$

So $\sigma\tau=\tau^{-1}\sigma$ as wished.