# Write $(12), (13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$ as product of two permutations, each with order 2.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

So in my book it's stated that every element of $S_4$ can be written as a product of two permutations, each with order 2.

I tried to do this, but got stuck with the elements $(12), (13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$, so basically the transitions.

Any tips on how to write the transitions in the mentioned form?

Comment: $(12)=((12)(34))(34)$

Comment: Note that in $S_{n}$, for any $n > 3$, every permutation can be written as the product of two involutions, i.e. of two elements of order $2$. See for instance [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497637/is-any-permutation-the-product-of-two-involutions).